# Компонент Joomla 1.5

Tags: веб-программирование, joomla, php

Добрый день..

Может ли кто-нибудь посоветовать бесплатный компонент для управления каталога с машинами, и online резервирования автомобилей.

Тематика сайта : аренда автомобилей.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такую штуку](http://domaintimes.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1320). Скорее всего, ручками допиливать придется.

Answer (score 0):

Распространенный компонент каталога для Joomla - Mosets Tree.
Посмотрите по функционалу подходит ли.

Может тогда попробовать модуль VirtueMart - интернет магазин?! И каталог и резервирование думаю есть, а корзину можно и не подключать.

Comment: к сожаленью он платный ( http://www.mosets.com/tree/tour/